# Statistical Operation over set of data to detect change in a value

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, statistics

I have a set of dummy data e.g. 100 points that I wish to do the following:

1. Use some statistical operation
2. use the result of the Step 1 and create a hash e.g. sha-256 or md-5

Then I want to change more than one data points within the set and perform the same steps above.

**Point to Prove**:

> I wish to leverage statistics of the given set as a *key* to perform a cryptographic hash for the set. If the set values are changed, I assume the statistical operation will provide a different value and in turn provide a different hash. If hashes don't match the sets are not the same.

By using mean of the set, will it be enough to detect changes to a set, even if the values changed are extremely small?

What other operation should I look into to perform step 1  of the query?

### Code Idea

```
import hashlib
# get Set
# Perform Step 1
h1 = hashlib.sha256()
h1.update(b'value from step1')

# change values within set
# perform Step 1
h2 = hashlib.sha256()
h2.update(b'new value from step2')

# check if h1 == h2
h1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean might make some problems for your purpose, because it is not unique to a dataset. That means you can never be sure if two data sets are the same, if you base your hash on the mean value of a data set.

Here an example:

Let's say your data set is [1,1,1]. Now you calculate the mean, which is 1. Next you create a hash of 1. Now, how do you make sure after changing **more than one** data point you don't end up with [1,0,2], [3,0,0] or any other data set that gives you a mean of 1 and therefore the same hash?

Standard deviation, variance and correlation lead into the same trap.

However, you can still be sure that two data sets with different hashes are not the same. It just doesn't work the other way around to say two datasets with the same hash are the same.

To minimize the chance of creating the same hash from two different data sets, you could calculate a Rabin Fingerprint of your data set and generate the hash from that. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint

Comment: Yes I was doubting whether mean would work in my case. I am looking for other statitical operation perhaps variance or standard deviation but I am not sure if that will be more useful

Comment: Variance and standard deviation have the same problem. I can elaborate if you wish. It always comes down to the problem that you can find different datasets that generate the same mean, std and var.

Comment: I understand, because variance and std. dev. are relying on mean (when one looks into the formula). My last bet was using correlation.

Comment: Correlation needs a second data set for comparison. So I guess you would need to have one fixed data set that you compare against. Then you run in the same problem again. For example Pearson Correlation of [1,1,1] (the fixed set) against [1,0,1] and [1,1,0] would deliver the same result.

Comment: If the data set increases to thousands of points and if each entry has a timestamp then manipulation might become hard right? I am not denying the fact that manipulation is totally avoided but I am just looking for a proof of concep which is dependent on the statistics of the dataset. Maybe you can elaborate your answer more with some suggestions on what could be a possible method to achieve it.

Comment: I edited the answer. After reading your question again, I realized you wanted to make sure that if two datasets give you different hashes, you know they are different. This is true. If it is ok for your proof of concept, that same hashes do not necessarily equal same data sets then everything is ok!

Comment: one more thing, Rabin fingerprints are for file systems. Is rabin fingerprint possible for JSON data. If in a program I have a python dict, can I obtain a Rabin fingerprint for it?

Comment: I never worked with Rabin fingerprints, I just stumbled over them searching for a solution to your problem. However, the formula on Wikipedia seems simple enough. Plug in the numbers in your dataset for m_0, m_1,..., m_n. n is the number of elements in your dataset. Now you have to find a irreducible polynomial, carry out the division and get the remainder. During my studies i used numpy.polidiv, maybe that helps you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189600/discussion-between-shan-desai-and-simon-wisotzki).